# iptables: Index of deletion too big BASH

Tags: linux, bash, iptables

I am having some difficulties setting a default iptables script as it won't run. It shows the error: iptables: Index of deletion too big 
I have tried re-ordering the rules, attempting to delete all first before adding, etc. but it doesn't seem to be helping. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -D FORWARD 1
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -D INPUT 5
iptables -D INPUT 4
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -D INPUT 3
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

the original IP tables looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  119 13723 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: This script doesn't *set up* an INPUT table entry #5, so how do you expect deleting it to reliably function?

Comment: To understand how this works at all, we'd need to see the tables as they exist before the script is run (and any analysis would be valid only with that starting state).

Comment: Also, this isn't bash-specific at all. You'd have the exact same problem if you ran the same iptables commands from Python, Java, C, etc.

Comment: A rule 5 exists within the INPUT chain by default, its the rule that REJECTS remaining traffic at the bottom of the chain. I want to remove this rule since I changed the default rule to DROP

Comment: No, a rule 5 does *not* exist by default -- the kernel initializes all chains to be empty. Your specific Linux distro might put in a rule 5, but it's not there before your distro's startup scripts put it there -- so the order of operations between when this is run and when your distro scripts run is critical.

Comment: Here are the original IP Tables. Im very sorry, I have no idea how to paste this to look like proper code:

Comment: Content that's essential to be able to answer the question should be edited into the question itself.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, this is clearly my first time using Stack Overflow, and this is my first thread ever here, and it is definitely not overly user friendly

Comment: To format content as code, select it and click the `{}` button. BTW, if it helps to understand the culture -- the goal (actually going back to the site's initial creation) is about building a good Q&A knowledgebase; helping people asking questions with their problems is more a side effect of that process than the overt goal, and ideally we'd eventually reach a place where almost everyone could find their question already asked and answered rather than needing to ask a new one at all.

Comment: ...hence, we care a lot about questions being generalized enough to be helpful to other people; having good titles, accurate tagging, etc.

Comment: I understand, and I appreciate your help despite my lack of experience on this site and formatting the code and questions properly. If I understand though, you're saying there is no rule 5 by default, but if thats the case, how would I remove that REJECT rule from the script if that command is causing errors?

Comment: Quick question -- is that `iptables -L` run immediately before the script? If this is being invoked at boot, you might put a `iptables -L --line-numbers >/tmp/some.log` or such at the first line, to see what the rules are *at that point in time*, and include the line numbers with it.

Comment: Beyond that -- what's your OS/distro (assuming you're using its default firewall configuration)?

Comment: (that said, does the error happen even with a manual invocation after you checked iptables manually, or only in the on-boot state?)

Comment: That is run after the command iptables -L -v and the OS I am using is Centos7. And yes Im using its default firewall configuration.

Comment: I'm suggesting `--line-numbers` specifically to have lines in the output that show the same number you need to use for the deletion process. Anyhow, to delete all REJECT rules, you could use something like this: `delete_reject_rules() { local table_name num; for table_name; do iptables -L "$table_name" --line-numbers | awk '$2 == "REJECT" { print $1 }' | tac | while IFS= read -r num; do iptables -D "$table_name" "$num"; done; done; }` -- with that function, `delete_reject_rules INPUT FORWARD` will delete all reject rules from both INPUT and FORWARD chains

Comment: see [Centos 7 save iptables settings](http://serverfault.com/questions/626521/centos-7-save-iptables-settings) over on ServerFault.

Comment: Alright, once again I very much appreciate the help. The reason I am attempting to write a script to do it is so I am deploy the script within several VMs rather than edit every individual list of rules. But I'll be fine either way.

Comment: Hmm. The ideal thing would probably be to write a script that modifies firewalld configuration -- that way your changes stick through reboot, service restart, etc; either that, or switch from firewalld to something else instead. I'd need a system using firewalld handy to test such a script, though, so I'm probably not the best person to answer this one.